# Sorting words to make a web output in java

Tags: java

I have finished a program in java that I am working on. I have completed my codes and everything, but my output does not show the correct way. It supposes to look like a web, but my output is not. I have posted my code. I am asking the community for education purposes not getting answers.

```
   import java.util.*;
    import static java.lang.System.*;

    public class FancyWordThree
    {
        private String[][] mat;

       public FancyWordThree(String s)
        {
            //size the matrix
          mat = new String[s.length()*4-3][s.length()*4-3];
            //use Arrays.fill() to fill in the matrix with spaces
          for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
          Arrays.fill(mat[i], " ");
          }
            //use a for loop to load in the letters into the matrix
          for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++){
          int at = 0;
          if (i ==mat.length-j-1 && i !=0 || s.length()-j ==i)
          mat[i][j] = s.charAt(at)+"";
                }
          }
        }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";
      for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < mat.length; j++){
      output = output+mat[i][j];
      }
      output = output +"\n";`enter code here`
      }
        return output+"\n\n";
    }
}
```

My runner

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class FancyWordThreeRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        //add code and test cases here
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new File ("mofancyword.dat"));
        int size = file.nextInt();
        file.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            String word = file.next();
         FancyWordThree test = new FancyWordThree(word);
         System.out.println(test);
       }

}
```

}

My output

```
A  
 A A 
A A  
 A   
A    



   A     
  A    A 
 A    A  
A    A   
    A    
   A     
  A      
 A       
A        



   A     
  A    A 
 A    A  
A    A   
    A    
   A     
  A      
 A       
A        



  I  
 I I 
I I  
 I   
I    



   C     
  C    C 
 C    C  
C    C   
    C    
   C     
  C      
 C       
C        



    W        
   W       W 
  W       W  
 W       W   
W       W    
       W     
      W      
     W       
    W        
   W         
  W          
 W           
W            



     T           
    T          T 
   T          T  
  T          T   
 T          T    
T          T     
          T      
         T       
        T        
       T         
      T          
     T           
    T            
   T             
  T              
 T               
T
```

[The supposed output click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKc0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've completed your program if you aren't getting the right output!

Like all problems, the key is to work out your algorithm before you try to turn it into code. In this case there is a pretty clear pattern: the first character is placed in 4 directions and then the word is spelt out from each of those positions in every direction but the direction the first character is placed in.

To make this pretty clear I'd start by turning the directions into an enumeration:

```
private enum Dir {
    NE(+1, +1), 
    SE(+1, -1), 
    SW(-1, -1), 
    NW(-1, +1);

    private final int xd;
    private final int yd;

    private Dir(int xd, int yd) {
        this.xd = xd;
        this.yd = yd;
    }
}
```

That means you can deal with a direction without having to worry about how to calculate movements in x and y.

Next write the code to output the values in a given direction:

```
private void setWebAt(String input, Dir dir) {
    int x = (dir.xd + 2) * (input.length() - 1);
    int y = (dir.yd + 2) * (input.length() - 1);
    Arrays.stream(Dir.values())
        .filter(d -> !d.equals(dir))
        .forEach(d -> IntStream.range(0, input.length())
            .forEach(i -> result[x + i * d.xd][y + i * d.yd] = input.charAt(i)));
}
```

Note the filter to prevent outputting the word in the given direction.

Ideally you should write unit tests for this code before continuing.

Finally, the code to output the four directions is pretty trivial:

```
Arrays.stream(Dir.values()).forEach(dir -> setWebAt(input, dir));
```

The rest is pretty trivial filler to initialise and print the array.

If you're not familiar with streams they can all be changed to `for` loops.